# Visual Studio 2017 dont read tsconfig.json

Tags: visual-studio, typescript2.0

I have a web project in Visual Studio 2017 with one Angular 4 component.
After publish the project to server, same files exists in obj directory.

As example:

```
App.Web\obj\Release-dev1\AspnetCompileMerge\Source\Scripts\app.ts
```

When I make rebuild project then tsc make error about dublicate class:

```
 Error      Build:Duplicate identifier 'Grid'.  App.Web\obj\Release-dev1\AspnetCompileMerge\Source\Scripts\app.ts   450
```

I've added in tsconfig.json

```
"exclude": [ "obj" ]
```

But that didnt fix it.

Property page TypeScript in project is blocked (because exists tsconfig file).

When I've deleted folder obj then make build is fine.

After to publish project the problem exists again.

How exclude folder (ex. obj) for compile TypeScript ?

Answer (score 2):

This will also help:

1. Open Solution Explorer
2. Right click on the tsconfig.json file and choose 'Exclude From
   Project'.

   You might see the tsconfig.json disappear from the Solution
   Explorer.

   In that case choose 'Show All Files' option from the top of the
   Solution Explorer toolbar.
3. Right click on the tsconfig.json and choose 'Include In Project'.

Answer (score 1):

**Where is tsconfig.json located ?**

Place for the tsconfig file is root folder in the project.